# Vw passat cc 2011

Tags: maintenance

2011 vw cc, machanic told me from LHS shock leaking need new set, because they are self stabilising shocks it will cost 800€, can't I put in normal shocks no?

Comment: Aftermarket could be an option and is often better and cheaper than OEM parts.  Also if you're talking about electronic shocks, it is possible to get working, used parts to save money.